# Streaming GPS data to QGIS from DELL internal NEO-M8 u-blox

Tags: qgis, gps

Dell 5434 with built in NEO-M8 u-blox. Appears to be working as checked with u-centre 22.07. In Device manager: Sensors shows u-blox GNSS location sensor. Ports (COM & LPT) u-blox Virtural Port (com 3).
In u-centre 22.07
connected to Port COM3 and shows correct location and streams data

QGIS
In GPS information panel
Autodetect:
Shows connecting on autodetect but no data streaming data box not green (showing data) is grey (should be green).

In GPS information panel
Serial device
If changed to serial device (which shows COM3:u-blox Virtual COM Port) it times out and no data is streamed

In GPS information panel-I have not used it
Gpsd
Host: local
Port:2947
Device: BLANK

I think this is a problem with QGIS not seeing the COM3 port?
out of interest tried:
https://www.handheldgroup.com/knowledge-base/connect-qgis-to-u-blox-gps/

Comment: One suggestion (not an answer) - the Virtual COM port only allows one application to connect at a time so make sure you disconnect u-centre before trying to connect QGIS.  My experience is that u-blox Virtual COM ports are very reliable!

Comment: Another thought here - a couple of years ago I found that some applications were unable to open Virtual COM Ports which were created using the u-blox Virtual COM Ports driver v3.00 to v3.10, but COM ports created using u-blox Virtual COM Ports driver v2.30 appeared to work with all apps.